# Warning: Attempt to present ZMNavigationController on **.ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, sdk

Guys i am facing an odd problem with `NavigationController`. Existing answers did not help at all !!!!

Here is basic scenario of the app:

> 1. There are two views - Main and Second view
> 2. In main view there is a button when i happen to tap goes into second view using segue.
> 3. In second view after i enter a certain field in text view and click on a button called "join" it triggers "joinMeeting()" function
>      and meeting should be joined.

However, when i do that debugger shows me:

> "Warning: Attempt to present  on
>   <***.ViewController: *****> whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!"

So i have read most of the tread and given that it happens because of **viewDidAppear** method but i have nth to be done before **viewDidAppear**. Everything happens after button is clicked.

> joinMeeting() is successfully called and print method returns 0 which means no issue[(https://developer.zoom.us/docs/ios/error-codes/)](https://developer.zoom.us/docs/ios/error-codes/) and successful SDK connection however after this **"Warning"** error is shown in debugger and nothing happens in the app.

If it helps following is the code that triggers joinBtn:

```
/**
Triggers when Join Button is clicked from second view.
*/
    @IBAction func joinMeeting(_ sender: Any) {
            if( activityID.text == "" ) {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Field is Blank", message: "Activity ID cannot be blank.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                return;
            }


            let ms: MobileRTCMeetingService? = MobileRTC.shared().getMeetingService()
            if ms != nil {
                ms?.delegate = self;

                // //For Join a meeting
                let paramDict: [AnyHashable: Any] = [
                    kMeetingParam_Username: kSDKUserName,
                    kMeetingParam_MeetingNumber: activityID.text!,
                ]

                let ret: MobileRTCMeetError? = ms?.joinMeeting(with: paramDict)
                print("onJoinaMeeting ret:\(String(describing: ret))")
            }
        }
```

Please help if anyone knows or have an idea on what i am missing here.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing this error?

Comment: After "let ret: MobileRTCMeetError? = ms?.joinMeeting(with: paramDict)" ... error is triggered

Comment: Then you should edit your question to include the definition of `joinMeeting(with:)`. Without a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your question is considered off-topic.

Comment: Sorry about that.. updated the question by a bit. Added "joinMeeting() is successfully"

Comment: `ms?.joinMeeting(with: paramDict)` cannot be calling the IBAction called `joinMeeting` since their function signatures are clearly different. It seems `MobileRTCMeetingService` has another method called `joinMeeting(with:)` and that is the one you are calling on the problematic line, not `joinMeeting(_:)`, which is an IBAction connected to your UIButton.

Comment: Hmm right i jst noticed that.. func name are both same.. i'll change UIButton action name and try it out but i doubt thats the problem.

Comment: nvm i solved it with the "UIStoryboard" method

Comment: If you managed to solve your issue, you should post your solution as an answer, otherwise your question won't be useful for future readers having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what solved the issue:**

**Storyboard Configuration:**
ViewController --Segue: Show--> JoinViewController

```
@IBAction func onClickJoin(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        //Main storyBoard
        let initialVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController

        let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)

        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialVC

        //Rest of the code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add Following code on that controller in which you  want to perform calling:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
  appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController  = self

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, none of the above solutions worked for me.
So Here is my solution.

Add this line

```
MobileRTC.shared().setMobileRTCRootController( self.navigationController)
```

=> When user taps of **Join Call Button**.

**Make sure these conditions should meet as well.**

1. ViewController which is used to open the ZOOM meeting should be **a part of root navigation controller**
2. DO NOT present modally the current Zoom Meeting Joining View Controller. Always push it to the root navigation controller.